# Tree/nested structures in Spark from relational data model

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-dataset

If i understand correctly, i could consider spark dataset as a list of objects of type `T`. How can two datasets be joined in a way that parent contains a list of children? But also a child would have the list of its own children...

One approach to this would be to do a `groupBy` of the children based on the key, but `collect_list` returns only one column and i suppose there is a better way to do this.

Wanted result is basically a dataset (list of customer objects?) of type `Customer`, but with additions:

- Each customer would have a list of invoices.
- Each invoice would have its own attributes, but also a list of items inside...
- ...and this can continue (a tree)

End result would then be something like

```
case class Customer(customer_id: Int, name: String, address: String, age: Int, invoices: List[Invoices])
case class Invoice(invoice_id: Int, customer_id: Int, invoice_num:String, date: Int, invoice_type: String, items: List[Items])
```

And to that result i would need to come from the following inputs:

```
case class Customer(customer_id: Int, name: String, address: String, age: Int)
case class Invoice(invoice_id: Int, customer_id: Int, invoice_num:String, date: Int, invoice_type: String)
case class InvoiceItem(item_id: Int, invoice_id: Int, num_of_items: Int, price: Double, total: Double)

    val customers_df = Seq(
       (11,"customer1", "address1", 10, "F")
      ,(12,"customer2", "address2", 20, "M")
      ,(13,"customer3", "address3", 30, "F")
    ).toDF("customer_id", "name", "address", "age", "sex")
    val customers_ds = customers_df.as[Customer].as("c")

    customers_ds.show

    val invoices_df = Seq(
       (21,11, "10101/1", 20181105, "manual")
      ,(22,11, "10101/2", 20181105, "manual")
      ,(23,11, "10101/3", 20181105, "manual")
      ,(24,12, "10101/4", 20181105, "generated")
      ,(25,12, "10101/5", 20181105, "pos")
    ).toDF("invoice_id", "customer_id", "invoice_num", "date", "invoice_type")
    val invoices_ds = invoices_df.as[Invoice].as("i")

    invoices_ds.show

    val invoice_items_df = Seq(
       (31, 21, 5, 10.0, 50.0)
      ,(32, 21, 3, 15.0, 45.0)
      ,(33, 22, 6, 11.0, 66.0)
      ,(34, 22, 7, 2.0, 14.0)
      ,(35, 23, 1, 100.0, 100.0)
      ,(36, 24, 4, 4.0, 16.0)
    ).toDF("item_id", "invoice_id", "num_of_items", "price", "total")
    val invoice_items_ds = invoice_items_df.as[InvoiceItem].as("ii")

    invoice_items_ds.show
```

In tables it looks like this:

```
+-----------+---------+--------+---+---+
|customer_id|     name| address|age|sex|
+-----------+---------+--------+---+---+
|         11|customer1|address1| 10|  F|
|         12|customer2|address2| 20|  M|
|         13|customer3|address3| 30|  F|
+-----------+---------+--------+---+---+

+----------+-----------+-----------+--------+------------+
|invoice_id|customer_id|invoice_num|    date|invoice_type|
+----------+-----------+-----------+--------+------------+
|        21|         11|    10101/1|20181105|      manual|
|        22|         11|    10101/2|20181105|      manual|
|        23|         11|    10101/3|20181105|      manual|
|        24|         12|    10101/4|20181105|   generated|
|        25|         12|    10101/5|20181105|         pos|
+----------+-----------+-----------+--------+------------+

+-------+----------+------------+-----+-----+
|item_id|invoice_id|num_of_items|price|total|
+-------+----------+------------+-----+-----+
|     31|        21|           5| 10.0| 50.0|
|     32|        21|           3| 15.0| 45.0|
|     33|        22|           6| 11.0| 66.0|
|     34|        22|           7|  2.0| 14.0|
|     35|        23|           1|100.0|100.0|
|     36|        24|           4|  4.0| 16.0|
+-------+----------+------------+-----+-----+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you are trying to read normalized data into a tree of Scala objects. You can certainly do this with Spark but Spark may not be the optimal tool for this. If the data is small-enough to fit in memory, which I assume is true from your question, object-relational mapping (ORM) libraries may be better suited for the job.

If you still want to use Spark, you are on the right path with `groupBy` and `collect_list`. What you are missing is the `struct()` function.

```
case class Customer(id: Int)
case class Invoice(id: Int, customer_id: Int)

val customers = spark.createDataset(Seq(Customer(1))).as("customers")
val invoices = spark.createDataset(Seq(Invoice(1, 1), Invoice(2, 1)))

case class CombinedCustomer(id: Int, invoices: Option[Seq[Invoice]])

customers
  .join(
    invoices
      .groupBy('customer_id)
      .agg(collect_list(struct('*)).as("invoices"))
      .withColumnRenamed("customer_id", "id"), 
    Seq("id"), "left_outer")
  .as[CombinedCustomer]
  .show
```

`struct('*)` builds a `StructType` column from the entire row. You can also pick any columns, e.g., `struct('x.as("colA"), 'colB)`.

This produces

```
+---+----------------+
| id|        invoices|
+---+----------------+
|  1|[[1, 1], [2, 1]]|
+---+----------------+
```

Now, in the case where the customer data is expected not to fit in memory, i.e., using a simple `collect` is not an option, there are a number of different strategies you can take.

The simplest, and one you should consider instead of collecting to the driver, requires that independent processing of each customer's data is acceptable. In that case, try using `map` and distribute the per-customer processing logic to the workers.

If independent processing by customer is not acceptable the general strategy is as follows:

1. Aggregate the data into structured rows as needed using the above approach.
2. Repartition the data to ensure that everything you need for processing is in a single partition.
3. (optionally) `sortWithinPartitions` to ensure that the data within a partition is ordered as you need it.
4. Use `mapPartitions`.

Comment: volume of data is going to be "big". big here means 100 milion records in input and processed daily. output is expected to be 200 times bigger without considering simulation/forecasting. this is why spark is on the table.

Isn't `struct('*)` missing a quote here? Since it can take all columns to make a `StructType`, is there a way to infer class members based on types coming from the **database** table (int, date...)?

Comment: Total size of output doesn't matter as much as whether your processing is per-customer or not. If the output is bigger than the input, persist the aggregated per-customer data. If you need to process across customers things get a lot more complicated and I cannot recommend an optimal approach without knowing the particulars. If, during processing, you'll only need pieces of invoices & items, make sure you are using Spark 2.4+ as it has some optimizations for reading partial struct data.

Comment: this example was rather simple to illustrate the problem; what i am actually doing is same thing, but with loans. customer does play a role and the data must be partitioned in the way that all data of one customer is processed on a single worker. 
what can be avoided is to nest invoies (loans) within a customer object and i could base all the calculation on the loan itself, then left-join customer information later, because it plays a role in aggregation. nevertheless, i need to nest other things to contain it within one loan.

Comment: That probably merits its own question but here is the gist of how you approach the problem. First, aggregate to the level you need as shown above. Then, partition by customer ID to ensure that all customer data is in the same partition and `sortWithinPartitions` on customer ID (and loan ID, etc.) so that all customer data is adjacent + ordered as you need it. If you increase the number of partitions a lot, you may be able to use `mapPartitions` and process everything easily that way. If you want to get fancy, you can use the ordering of the data for efficient iteration.

Comment: thank you for the answers, this is what i was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Spark-SQL and have one dataset each for customer, invoices and items. 
Then you can simply use joins and aggregate functions between these datasets to get desired output.

Spark SQL have very negligible performance difference between sql style and programmatic way.